# Scala Map Function

Tags: scala, scala-collections

I need some help to solve this issue I've faced using scala map function. 
I've loaded a text file delimited by tab.

The Values are like following: 
RDD: org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[String]

Array[String]=Array(200110 1220 THEFT, 200112 2020 BATTERY, 200101 1010 DAMAGE, ....)

What I'd like to do is to get the a RDD like (1220 THEFT, 2020 BATTERY, 1010 DAMAGE, ....)

I've tried the following, but it's just throwing errors.

```
val crimeData = sc.textFile("/user/user_dir/crime_data")
val crimeTest = crimeData.map(crime => { 
val b = crime.split(",")
val c = b(0).split(" ")
((c(1),c(2)))
})
```

When I run this code all I get back is an ArrayOutOfBoundsExeception: 1

I know it's throwing this error cos It can't access position 1, but I don't know how to get the results the way I want.

Some Help Please!

Comment: What does the text file look like?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**I could make the code works doing like this**

```
val crimeTest = crimeData.map(rec => {
val b = rec.split(" ")
val c = b(0).split("\t")
((c(1), c(2)))

})
```

So my final results were like that:

(7866, THEFT)

(6525, BATTERY)

(4714, NARCOTICS)

....

Answer (score 1):

I don't think the following code is needed.`val b = Crime.split(",")` In crimeData,  each piece of data processed is `"200110 1220 THEFT"`, so we don't need to use comma to split.

```
val crimeTest = crimeData.filter(_.split(" ").length == 3)
      .map(crime => {
      val c = crime.split(" ")
      (c(1), c(2))
    })
```

Hope it helps you.

Comment: While this code may resolve the OP's issue, it is best to include an explanation as to how your code addresses the OP's issue. In this way, future visitors can learn from your post, and apply it to their own code. SO is not a coding service, but a resource for knowledge. Also, high quality, complete answers are more likely to be upvoted. These features, along with the requirement that all posts are self-contained, are some of the strengths of SO as a platform, that differentiates it from forums. You can edit to add additional info &/or to supplement your explanations with source documentation.

Comment: @ysf Thanks for your suggestion , I will do that.

Comment: Hi @kai.tian your code didn't work, but thanks for taking the time to try to help me out. I figured out a way that works, I'll update and post the code

Comment: @ron Really? what does the input text file look like?